# How can I have VBA export CSV file based on two variables in the URL?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

```
Sub DownloadKeyRatios(ByVal stockTicker As String, ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date, ByVal DestinationCell As String, ByVal freq As String)
    Dim qurl As String
    Dim StartMonth, StartDay, StartYear, EndMonth, EndDay, EndYear As String
    Dim C As WorkbookConnection
    StartMonth = Format(Month(StartDate) - 1, "00")
    StartDay = Format(Day(StartDate), "00")
    StartYear = Format(Year(StartDate), "00")

    EndMonth = Format(Month(EndDate) - 1, "00")
    EndDay = Format(Day(EndDate), "00")
    EndYear = Format(Year(EndDate), "00")
    qurl = "URL;http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&callback=?&t=XNYS:" + stockTicker + "&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order"

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=qurl, Destination:=Range(DestinationCell))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        '    .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        '    .RefreshPeriod = 0
        '    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        '    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        '    .WebTables = "20"
        '    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        '    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        '    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        '    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        '    .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
ErrorHandler:

End Sub
```

I would like for the code to run both XNYS and XNAS in the qurl and pull the CSV files. Is there anyway to do that? I have the `stockTicker` as a variable, but would rather it just run the other XNAS on error.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. So, you want to run the code for another URL again? If so, just change the URL for XNYS or XNAS or whatever you want and copy the code to the end of the sub. If you want to do it a bit more sophisticated you can also loop an array of URLs. But that's it. Or am I completely off topic here?

Comment: I got it figured out. I don't have a clue what I'm doing, but so far I've managed to make everything work without knowing a thing about VBA. The internet is amazing. And yes, you were on topic. I wanted to loop it, but I didn't know how. Figured it out though. Thanks.